# Xcode 6 with iOS 8 SDK: no Devices in Organizer

Tags: installation, ios8, xcode6, beta

## OS X 10.9.4

Steps:

1. Install Xcode 6 w/ iOS 8 SDK GM Seed
2. Run Xcode
3. Go to Window | Organizer
4. Devices not available

End result is I can't update device with iOS 8, so can't test properly or create binaries. Tried with iTunes as well. See attached for screenshot.

Has anyone had this problem? If so, were you able to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is now in Window > Devices. See image below:

[image: Xcode 6 Window > Devices]

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to update devices with iOS 8 GM Seed? I didn't see anything.

Comment: It is possible if you're on developer program. What didn't you see?

Comment: Before it was under Software Version, then Other Version..., select the firmware file, then Restore iPhone. Not seeing anything like Update or Restore.

Comment: You have to do it using iTunes restore

Comment: Aaaaghhh !  Why does Apple DO this to us ?